# How to get around memory allocation error in python nosetest?

Tags: python

I have a python script to allocate a huge memory space and eventually ended up overflow. Is there anyway nosetests can peacefully handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to survive such a thing would be to have your test fixture run that particular test in a subcommand using `subprocess.Popen()`, and capture its output and error code so that you can see the nonzero error code and “out of memory” traceback that result. Note that `sys.executable` is the full path to the current Python executable, if that helps you build a `Popen()` command line to run Python on the little test script that runs out of memory.

Once a process it out of memory, there is typically no way to recover, because nearly anything it might try to do — format a string to print out, for example — takes even *more* memory which is, by definition, now exhausted. :)